# Customizing (disabling) security settings for IE control 

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, components

I have a job that takes screen shot of a website on a given URL. IE control is instantiated inside the job (which is a console app). However the pages are not rendered correctly the security settings of the server on which the job is running. I found in some answers taht security settings can be controlled by [IInternetSecurityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827940/override-ie-privacy-settings-using-iinternetsecuritymanager-in-webbrowser-contro).

I created a class that inherits from WebBrowser class and implements this interface and a couple of others similarly to the way it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996730/custom-iinternetsecuritymanager-not-being-called-with-dialogs). But this didn't solve my problem. Does this interface requires some activation or a special call in order to influence the behavior of the control.

Shortly I need somehow to customize security settings for the IE control.

Answer (score 2):

IE Enhanced Security Configuration is not something that can be disabled in code as far as I know. I think it can only be disabled on the server or via Group Policy.

It is designed to be an ultra-restricted environment for web browsers running on servers, and it is enabled for all users by default IIRC.

Your choices are: disable it on the server (or via group policy), or add the target site to the list of trusted sites in IE. I *think* a trusted site works normally, even under IE ESC.

Comment: The problem is that if I have a new Url I need to add it manually to the trusted sites. Isn't it possible to override some security behavior for the IE control?

Comment: I think the answer is no if you are running this on a server. The whole idea behind this is to make it very difficult for sinister code or websites to be able to hijack the server - I'm not sure you'll be able to find a code solution - or the very idea of IE ESC would be flawed. Is it not possible to arrange for it to be disabled by the server's sysadmin, at least for standard users?

Comment: Well it's not that it is impossible but we a trying to keep all machines with standard settings as much as possible in case we need replication, back up or anything else. Thank you very much for your answers