# How to detect Internet Explorer Enhanced Security when using embedded WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I use the native browser control (System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser) in a windows forms application.
Now I want to load an HTML File that is embeded in my application.

I get the following message for example on Windows Server 2012 R2:

[image: eroor message of application]

I do not want to change the security settings on the target system. But I want to detect this problem and give the user instructions on how to fix this with a less intimidating message box I define myself.

Is there a way to do so in a windows forms application with c#?

I read the article here:
[How to bypass Internet Explorer Enhanced Security when using embedded WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997720/how-to-bypass-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-when-using-embedded-webbrowser)

But that is not what I want to try to accomplish.
And I also searched for other solutions on the web.

So I want to accomplish that I can detect that I can not load the page. And instead of showing the windows/internet explorer error I want to show an instruction/dialog that I defined myself in the application.